# Is there a canonical "composition over inheritance" question?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

Today I answered this question:

[Should I use strategy design pattern or something else?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/299552/22815)

After some back and forth with the asker in the comments, I thought it prudent to bring up the point that composition would be better than inheritance in his design.

I searched the main site looking for a good question on the topic of "composition over inheritance" but could not find a *good* one with lots of useful information, examples, etc. that demonstrate the strengths and weaknesses and makes a convincing argument in favor of composition. I ended up linking to a *good enough* question but was not satisfied with it.

Is there a question on the main site that would be a good candidate as the canonical "composition over inheritance" question that would be a good question to which to link when writing answers that advocate for composition instead of inheritance?

If not, I will consider writing up a self-answered CW Q/A.

Comment: I would also like to point out that there are plenty of _answers_ to other questions with good information, but I could not find a good _question_ on this topic. Ideally, all of the relevant information would be contained in a single canonical question, not strewn across multiple other, unrelated questions.

Comment: Normally when someone asks a question about "Why is X better than Y?" or "Why does everyone say X is better than Y?" we close it as opinion, too broad or unclear. So it's entirely possible we had a question kind of like this and eventually closed and/or deleted it.

Comment: @Ixrec I think this is one of the exceptions to the rule. While certainly there is some opinion here, it is not _primarily_ opinion-based because there is broad consensus on the topic. But yes, it is entirely possible that such a question is deleted.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure with you writing it (and declaring it as canonical) it'd avoid that fate and hopefully be of some use.

Comment: @Ixrec this topic comes up frequently enough when answering design questions that it is worth having a reference to point to. I just don't want to write up a dupe.

Comment: [two of them are listed here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/156848/designing-a-library-that-is-easy-to-use-composition-or-inheritance)

Comment: @gnat I don't think I am convinced of the quality of the questions or their answers. There is some good information in there, but it is a bit sparse.

Comment: well first question is more about history, a convenient target when people ask where this came from. [Top voted answer in second question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/134115/31260) looks fairly solid to me. Granted it's large and not very decisive but that's because the topic itself is such. If you want something more instructive, consider [this answer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/12446/31260) in one of the dupes - per my reading, answerer managed to make it concise without too much compromising on accuracy

Comment: I know my design patterns book says 'prefer composition over inheritance'. The one answer I've read which I like and you may want to reference if you do write one up: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/282024/should-i-use-inheritance-to-differentiate-objects-even-if-they-have-the-same-fie/283336#comment582614_283336

Comment: While not the most ideal of names, consider [Where does this concept of “favor composition over inheritance” come from?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/65179/where-does-this-concept-of-favor-composition-over-inheritance-come-from) ?

Answer (score 4):

Self-answered/Canonical questions get a bit of a free pass on Stack Overflow, if the question/answer pair is good.  In particular, if the answer makes a really good target for questions that are repeatedly asked often, it often gets a pass, and deservedly so.

For good examples of these kinds of questions, see:

- [PHP mail form doesn't complete sending email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644436/php-mail-form-doesnt-complete-sending-e-mail)

and

- [How to fix "Headers Already Sent" error in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

...both of which are referenced in the PHP Tag Wiki.

The PHP Tag Wiki, by the way, is the *right* way to create a tag wiki.  It is a shining example of what Tag Wikis should look like.

Some more examples of excellent canonical question/answer pairs:

- [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)
- [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)  (which also has a Java counterpart)
- The infamous [Definitive C++ Book List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Some questions just get lucky:

- [How do Javascript Closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Anyway, the way you find these questions is by looking through the Tag Wikis.  All of the decent tag wikis have a list of Frequently Asked Questions that the tag community sees as worthy enough to reference in the tag wiki.

[By the way...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance)